# Having issues with jmeter sockets

Tags: jmeter

I'm Getting this error while executing script
[image: Jmeter websocket settings]

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-10-30 15:58:38 PKT
Load time: 5005
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 
Response message: 

[Execution Flow]
 - Opening new connection
 - Using response message pattern ""
 - Using disconnect pattern ""
 - Waiting for the server connection for 5000 MILLISECONDS
 - Cannot connect to the remote server


[Variables]
 - Message count: 0


[Problems]
 - Unexpected error: null
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.sendMessage(ServiceSocket.java:189)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:141)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [ServiceSocket line 189](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/blob/master/src/main/java/JMeter/plugins/functional/samplers/websocket/ServiceSocket.java#L189) it appears that the `session` object is null, check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, it might be the case you plugin installation is corrupt (i.e. missing [dependencies](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki/Dependencies))

In general I would recommend switching to [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

this version is more up-to-date and has way more features.

Comment: Hi, I've also used the other plugin,,,,, but it gives error of timeout. I dont understand why